# Power series for an infinite product.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, infinite-product

Let $x$ be a real number with magnitude less than 1. Develop in a power series in $z$ the infinite product:

$$(1+xz)(1+x^{2}z)(1+x^{3}z)\cdots$$

I have tried multiplying terms in various ways, but have yet to find a pattern. Any suggestions?

Comment: The case $z=-1$ is already **not at all** evident. See (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PentagonalNumberTheorem.html). The general case deals with elliptical functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coefficient of $z^k$ in the product
$$ (1+xz)(1+x^2 z)(1+x^3 z)\cdot\ldots \tag{1}$$
is given by the sum
$$ \sum_{\substack{\,\,A\subset \mathbb{N}^+ \\ |A|=k}}\prod_{a\in A}x^a =\sum_{m\geq \frac{k(k+1)}{2}}Q(m,k)\,x^m\tag{2}$$
where $Q(m,k)$ denotes the [ways for partitioning $m$ into $k$ distinct parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html).
$(1)$ multiplied by $(1+z)$ is a [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: And the downvote is for... ?

Comment: This answer is good so I upvoted it. :)