# Lower bound of product.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

We have the product :
$$\prod{(1-\frac{1}{2^i})}$$ I know that product has upper bound and possibly has lower bound.
My question is : how can I get the lower bound of this product?
My idea was to estimate this product with other product , but I didn't get the product with non-zero limit.

Comment: This is a product, not a series or sum.

Comment: @RobertIsrael sry, is it better now ?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean. Do you consider (by coming back to the definition of an infinite product) $a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n{(1-\frac{1}{2^i})}$ and want to analyse a lower bound of this sequence ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, it's better to say so. I want to analyze the lower bound of this sequence

Comment: In other words, you want to prove that this product converges to a positive number?

Comment: @Crostul I now that this product less than one, but I want to know the lower bound.

Comment: As I explain in my (partial) answer, asking "the" lower bound, is the same as asking for an (explicit ...) value of the product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe for $n\geq 4$ we have
\begin{align}
2^n \geq n^2
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\prod^\infty_{n=4}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \leq \prod^\infty_{n=4}\left( 1- \frac{1}{2^n}\right)
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\prod^\infty_{n=2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \leq 
\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^2} \right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^3} \right)}
\prod^\infty_{n=1}\left( 1- \frac{1}{2^n}\right). 
\end{align}
Thus, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{63}{256}= \frac{63}{128}\prod^\infty_{n=2}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2} \right)\leq \prod^\infty_{n=1}\left( 1- \frac{1}{2^n}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Your lower bound ($\approx 0.246...$) is rather satisfying because the "true value" is $\approx 0.288...$

Answer (score 1):

(very partial answer)

Sequence $a_n:=\prod_{i=1}^n{(1-\frac{1}{2^i})}$ is positive (evident) and decreasing because $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a_{n}=(1-\frac{1}{2^n})a_{n-1}$. As it is bounded by below by $O$, it converges to its lower bound, by a classical result in analysis.

In particular, it is the same thing to speak about "the" lower bound of sequence ($a_n$) and the "value" of the infinite product.

I don't know of a simple expression of this limit. Nevertheless, have a look to the recent following question which generalizes yours:([Power series for an infinite product.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1918294)) (take $x=1/2$ and $z=1$) ; it shows how to convert this infinite product into a series.